# What is Cov(X - Y),

Tags: covariance

What is Cov(X - Y), where Cov is covariance?
Cov(X - Y) not Cov(X,Y). That is covariance of difference of two random variables like we have as Var(X - Y) = Var(X) + Var(Y) - 2Cov(X,Y)

Comment: It doesn't make sense covariance is a relationship between 2 random variables. Although Z=X-Y is a function of two random variables, itis still just a single variable.

Comment: I think I remember someone using "Cov" to denote a variance-covariance matrix. So it could make sense if $X$ and $Y$ were vectors

Comment: Time for the OP to tell us what he means and what is the source where he found it.

Answer (score 5):

Covariance is only defined between two jointly-distributed real-valued random variables. Hence, $\operatorname{Cov}(X-Y)$ does not make sense. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance#Definition).

Comment: I guess if two people say it, it becomes more convincing especially if the OP looks at your wikipedia link.  Maybe the intention was to ask for Cov(X-Y, X-Y) which would be Var(X-Y).  Joseph if you really had something else in mind tell us and we may be able to answer.

Comment: Covariance also applies to discrete random variables.

Comment: @user8463728  "real-valued" is used here as opposed to eg complex-valued or vector-valued, not meaning continuous.

Comment: Yh that is correct

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you want to know what is COV(X-Y, X-Y) which is simple the Var(X - Y) which in turn equals Var(X) + Var(Y) - 2*COV(X,Y)

Comment: (-1) This repeats the comment by Michael Chernick on a different answer and a definition stated in the question itself. It adds no new information to the thread.